# Arch: pactree equivalent for AUR

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

`pactree -s` is invaluable for finding dependencies in the official repositories.

How can I do the equivalent in the AUR?

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: @bonanza sadly not :(

Comment: The best thing I found so far: `yay -Si packagename` and then parse the output of it. Works also for non-installed AUR packages

Comment: is there still no solution for this?? i can't find anything decent..